# Ubuntu 20.04 Froze 3 Times - Always When On Stack Exchange Academia!

Tags: freeze, swap

Ubuntu freezing is not an unusual event.
But Ubuntu freezing after a short time on the same sub-site of Stack Exchange is a bit more of a coincidence than I would be willing to swallow.

I've migrated my Dell Inspiron 15 5000 i5 7200U 8 GB RAM to Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10 a week ago.
After all the usual hassles, e.g. configuring my desktop, getting a driver for my graphics card, migrating email on Thunderbird, installing favorite IDEs, text editors, databases, etc., I achieved a low SDD footprint (50 GB versus 170 GB with Windows) and fast response times in apps.

But while browsing on SE Academia, my system has frozen 3 times. It does not fail initially when on it. It does not fail when I try something like commenting or posting a response. But usually after doing a comment or just after 5 minutes of browsing.

It's all very curious.
But of course it's also very inconvenient as the only way out of the freeze is to force the machine to stop by holding the power button down. This of course loses me all my open windows and apps, which is a drag.

Can anyone suggest any reason or remedy for this increasingly common and vexing issue ?

**EDIT**

```
$ free -h

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          7.6Gi       4.1Gi       440Mi       239Mi       3.1Gi       3.0Gi

Swap:         2.0Gi        31Mi       2.0Gi


$ sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60


$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab

/swapfile    none            swap    sw              0       0


$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

1.2.8
```

Make: Dell

Model: Inspiron 15 5567

CPU: i5-7200U @2.5 GHz

RAM: 7967684 KiB

GPU: AMD Radeon R7 M445 4 GB (Driver: Mesa amdgpu)

**ACTIONS  EDIT**

```
~$ sudo swapoff -a

[sudo] password for tk: **************

~$ sudo rm -i /swapfile 

rm: remove regular file '/swapfile'? y

~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile 
bs=1M count=4096

4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 23.5976 s, 182 MB/s

~$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile

~$ sudo mkswap /swapfile

Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 4 GiB (4294963200 bytes)
no label, UUID=e44ca198-4f3b-4ecd-87b7-c1d7fa73a5ac

~$ sudo swapon /swapfile

~$ free -h 

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       2.7Gi       135Mi        54Mi       4.7Gi       4.5Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi

~$  sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab

/swapfile     none     swap    sw     0     0

~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

ls: cannot access '/home/tk/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No     such file or directory

~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 68

drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Oct 23 12:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 23 17:01 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 31 17:29 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 23 12:36 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  5 15:05 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

**MEMTEST REPORT**

[image: Memtest Report]

Comment: Read `man mkswap swapon` I'd suggest 1.5xRAM, or 12GB.

Comment: You see no significance to SE Academia ? (!)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`, and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @waltinator 1.5xRAM is a very old school recommendation. You really don't need a 12G swap... unless maybe if you're hibernating.

Comment: @heynnema  Machine specs displayed in edited question.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series is not specific enough for me to find the current BIOS. Do you have a specific 5xxx number for me?

Comment: @heynnema Looks like 5567 - see order form image. I have been wondering about my BIOS as it always tried to revert to hardware checking on startup and I have to press F12 and then press enter on the SDD Drive from the boot option list. This should all be automatic.

Comment: Step 1: bios update.  step 2: upgrade ram (8GB is 'standard' but if you're going to be doing large scale web browsing you'll need space for your browser to use).  do you have any plugins, etc. running in your browser by the way?  Sometimes those interfere.

Comment: @Thomas Ward I have a small number of either required (Open H264 Video Codec built-into FF) or operationally desirable plugins for Chrome and Opera like custom homepage or ad-blocker.

Comment: @Thomas Ward I agree that 16 GB is always better than 8 GB but short of an upgrade ought I deploy a swapspace ?

Comment: @Trunk yes, if your system is constantly using all your RAM.  Or you intend to run a lot of processes ;)

Comment: @Thomas Ward All right. I'll do that and report back in a few days of "normal use". Thanks to all here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BIOS**

Dell Inspiron 15 5567

You have BIOS 1.2.8.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.3.1, dated Oct 20, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=khpvm&oscode=wt64a&productcode=inspiron-15-5567-laptop).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Swap**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: New BIOS update added and SDD drive put as #1 in boot order. All going well. Now - what about swapspace ? Do I follow the 1.5XRAM suggestion ?

Comment: @Trunk Please see my update regarding swap in my answer.

Comment: Suggested actions implemented. One thing certain: there is no preferred freezing of my Ubuntu system when on SE Academia. It would freeze on **any** site if I was there long enough.

Comment: (I see you have disabled @ calls) But I'm a bit concerned at the instability of Ubuntu (I chose Ubuntu as a sys admin I met said it was stable) over a new installation and what I'd regard as a "light workload" . . . Of a 250 GB SSD drive, I have a total of 52.9 GB used. During freeze events, all I was using was a few browser windows, most dormant. If it freezes under this light load, what will it do in a server situation ?

Comment: @Trunk "@ calls" are not required if you're responding directly to my answer. There may be other reasons for your freezing, but we've eliminated the most obvious things. Once hashed out on your system, Ubuntu is a good platform. If you still have problems we'll take a look at your gnome-shell extensions. Try it with the newer BIOS and the larger /swapfile, and report back.

Comment: @Trunk Status please...

Comment: It's not seized yet so far. If it does, I'll increase the swap-space to 8 GB and monitor. It seems that Ubuntu 20.04 uses ~ 7 GB alone. So a big & demanding app like Inkscape or GIMP would bust out the RAM alone. I've configured Ubuntu to do all advised here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrI5c9PXS5k  bar the proprietary driver. Note **preload** (puts often-used apps in RAM) and hardware acceleration via GPU for Firefox.

Comment: @Trunk You did the BIOS update, yes? Shouldn't really be any reason to increase the /swapfile further. Remove `preload`... it'll only make things worse... and without watching the video, there might be more things that are more harmful than helpful.

Comment: Yes, new BIOS added 2 days ago. I thought you'd advise removal of **preload** ! I see no other things that would slow it. Another YT video advocates lowering swappiness to 10 . . . fine if you have plenty of RAM space, but not so with me. RAM at ~ 50%, swap at < 1%

Comment: Yup! No `preload` and no vm.swappiness=10 for sure! As you say *"It's not seized so far"*, maybe we have it fixed with my answer. If it sticks, please remember to accept it for me. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNX7HgcWqHc  #23 on this video recommends having an Xkill shortcut key to close a seizing app. But I wonder if we could set up an event log (or access existing logs) that would provide more detail on seizure situations ?

Comment: @Trunk After the BIOS update, and the swap update, are you still having problems? If so, I'll give you instructions on testing the memory. Report back.

Comment: No, not any problem so far today. But if they're not too extensive, please post them or a link to them. Linux Bible (Negus) for order soon -  please advise if there's a better one.

Comment: @Trunk I added the memory stuff to my answer for you.

Comment: Seized just now while browsing on Google News. Xkill key no use either. I'll raise swap space to 12 GB and monitor.

Comment: @Trunk Rather than increasing the swap further, I'd first run `memtest`. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Gnome extensions queries appended to post edit. Will try to do memory chack overnight if possible.

Comment: @Trunk Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and turn off all of the extensions by gcampax.github.com, restart gnome-shell or reboot, and see if that helps. Do you have any Chrome/Firefox extensions installed? Report back.

Comment: Firefox has required OpenH264 Codec and Shockwave Flash (on request activation). Chrome has Auto Clear Browser plus exts for opening docs, spreadsheets and slides - latter 3 now off. Opera has Homepage and Ad Blocker.

Comment: Attempts to run memtest according to its README instructions have not worked. Nothing is seen by the BIOS on the USB to run. In fact the USB (2 of them now) are corrupted and unmountable. Is this the **dd** disaster you alluded to ?

Comment: @Trunk Try using Ubuntu's own `Startup Disk Creator` and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Just got memtest done - report appended to question. 2 hours. Seems AOK.

Comment: @Trunk  With the exception of any disabled gnome-shell extensions, it sounds like your computer is ok now, yes?

Comment: No seizing lately. I doubt if Gnome extensions would be doing much to it. The Firefox browser (my usual one) was allowed use the GPU to speed up rendering via *about:config* then *layers.acceleration.force-enabled*. Apart from that I can think of much else. Decided against Linux Bible as it´s mostly about RH.

Comment: Did a full reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04 and all the above recommendations about swap-space (12 GB), extensions and other possible drags. No seizures noted so far. Maybe something done wrong at initial install ?

Comment: @Trunk Thanks for the update!